# Windows Server 2012, IIS, and Digest

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, digest

I recently got TWO IIS servers running perfectly smooth. I was able to access these from the outside with no problem, however as of a few days ago, out of no where.. when I try to access IIS Server A from the outside, I get a login prompt for DIGEST.

Digest is not installed under IIS in the Add Roles and Features" tool. The other server still works just fine. I have not done any updates since I booted them so I don't know why this is happening now :(

I am new to Windows Server 2012 and I don't have much of a clue where to go from here. Any pointers in the right direction will be most helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a fault by Windows Server 2012 R2. You have to uninstall the workfolder feature. It took me several nights.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. I did a grep search for the word "digest" in any "*.config" file on the server. I finally figured out that my C:\Windows\System32\SyncShareSvc.config had digest turned on. This is related to the Windows Sync Share service and the  “Work Folders” feature.

We did not need that service, so our solution was to remove the Work Folders feature from "Turn Windows Features on and Off" > "File and Storage Services" > File and iSCSI Services" > "Work Folders". After that, we were no longer prompted for Digest authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Look in your IIS W3SVC logs and trace back to the first time it did that and look to see what changed on the server.  Odds are something changed something.  Don't rule out that someone else changed it without your permission..

Answer (score 0):

Below works for me, just go through your server roles then remove work folder

I had a similar problem. I did a grep search for the word "digest" in any "*.config" file on the server. I finally figured out that my C:\Windows\System32\SyncShareSvc.config had digest turned on. This is related to the Windows Sync Share service and the “Work Folders” feature.